# Need to wire "C" wire to thermostat

Tags: hvac, furnace, nest

[image: furnace boards]

This is my furnace board. I don't see anything with a C terminal. Are there any connections on this board that I can use as a "C" terminal?

Below is the thermostat I'm trying to hook up. This is how it was wired at my old house.

Is this wiring correct?

- Furnace Board R to Thermostat 24RH
- Furnace Board terminal between R and W to Thermostat 24V Com
- Furnace Board W to Thermostat W1
- Furnace Board Y to Thermostat Y1
- Furnace Board G to Thermostat G

[image: Thermostat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's the terminal between R and W

See the white wire coming from the cable to the A/C compressor? Since the red wire in that cable goes to the Y terminal, the white wire in that cable has only one place it can go for the A/C to work, and that is the C terminal on the control board or its equivalent transformer terminal.

P.S. as to how you have the thermostat hooked up? It's spot on.

Comment: it's not well secured and seems milimeters away from popping out.

Comment: Do mind checking my proposed wiring to the thermostat, and let me know if its correct?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for that control board can be found here

**ST9160A-C Electronic Fan Timers - Honeywell**
 https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-1057.pdf

As `@ratchet freak` mentioned, the wiring needs to be redone. The inside of a furnace is noisy, dusty and subject to vibration and temperature variations. Loose connections create problems that are difficult to diagnose.

The end of the wires should be fashioned into a reversed question mark so they hook properly to the screw terminals.

https://www.hunker.com/13414272/proper-technique-to-wrap-an-electrical-wire-around-a-screw-terminal

Comment: Do mind checking my proposed wiring to the thermostat, and let me know if its correct?